# How to upgrade to latest OS on Macbook Air?

Tags: macos, upgrade

I have an Early 2014 13" MacBook Air running OS X 10.9.5 Mavericks.
In my attempt to upgrade Google Chrome to the latest version, I discovered my Chrome version only went up to 65. (The latest Google Chrome is already at version 80). The reason Chrome won't give me the latest update is because my OS is not supported anymore. So obviously I now want to install the latest OS X.

Unfortunately, when I go to:  Apple > Software Update the App Store opens to the Updates tab and is empty, saying "No Updates Available".

Even if I do a search in the app store, I can't find any of the new OS X versions.

How do I find and update to the latest OS X?

Comment: Try this [link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-catalina/id1466841314?ls=1&mt=12).

Answer (score 1):

The new macOS is not displaying because you are not signed into the App Store with your AppleID.

Since you are in the category of "OS X 10.10 Yosemite or earlier" (10.9 is before 10.10), you might have some trouble signing in because your OS does not support two-factor authentication.

Use [two step verification](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204152):

When you open the App Store and try to sign in, you may see some text in red saying "Please type your password followed by the security code".

Check your phone. Your phone may ask if you allow the login from a certain device; click "allow". It will then show you a pin number.

So if your password is "hushpuppies" and the pin on your phone is "123456", type "hushpuppies123456" in the password field.

After you have signed in, you still might not see anything in the "updates" tab. Try looking at the "featured" tab to see if the OS is there. Once you find it, (in my case, there was a banner in the featured tab for "Catalina") click the "get" button and the download will start.

Run the downloaded installer and follow instructions.

Comment: "Run the downloaded installer and follow instructions."  How do you run it and what instructions are you referring to?

Comment: the question is also vague in relation to the answer because there are several MBA models that *cannot* upgrade to the latest OS.  These are only able to upgrade to their latest *supported* version of macOS